# How can I plot some data from a non-normal data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, plotly

Here is the code that I am putting together.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h8/current/default.htm'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[10]
df.shape
list(df)
type(df)

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(df['Commercial and industrial loans'])
fig.show()
```

The code works, except for the plotting part.  The object is: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

However, something looks weird to me, because when I run `list(df)`, I get this:

```
[('Account', 'Account'),
 ('Account', 'Account.1'),
 ('2019 Aug', '2019 Aug'),
 ('2020 Feb', '2020 Feb'),
 ('2020 Mar', '2020 Mar'),
 ('2020 Apr', '2020 Apr'),
 ('2020 May', '2020 May'),
 ('2020 Jun', '2020 Jun'),
 ('2020 Jul', '2020 Jul'),
 ('2020 Aug', '2020 Aug'),
 ('Week ending', 'Aug 12'),
 ('Week ending', 'Aug 19'),
 ('Week ending', 'Aug 26'),
 ('Week ending', 'Sep 02')]
```

That doesn't look like any data frame that I have seen before.  Ultimately, I am trying to plot the data for the 'Commercial and industrial loans' account.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The data doesn't look very clean. and what you have is called `multiIndex`.
Based on your use case I made the below code.

```
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[10]

df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1) #drop the first column 0,1,2 etc
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0) #remove the upper level of multi Index
df.rename(columns = {'Account.1':'Account'}, inplace = True) #Rename Columns
df = df.set_index('Account').transpose() #Transpose the data

#Plot
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df,y = 'Commercial and industrial loans',x = df.index)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This this looks right to me.  However, when I run your code in my environment, I don't actually get the chart.  fig seems fine, but fig.show() doesn't actually produce anything.

Comment: `fig.show()` works for me in both in shell and jupyter notebook. What are you using?  Using in shell opens a browser to render.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.6 and Spyder 4.0.1.  I Googled for a solution, of course, but I didn't find anything useful.  Also, this DOES WORK when I run it in a Jupyter Notebook, and the same laptop.

Comment: You can try the offline version `from plotly.offline import plot` then
`plot(fig)`

Comment: Yeap, that works!!!  Thanks for all the help here!!!